# React-Router send user to another route

Tags: react-router

Let's say the user has to enter some text into a box, and if the text matches a certain pattern, I send them to another route. How do I do that?

I've been trying to do:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigation } from 'react-router';

React.createClass({
  mixins: [Navigation],
  handleChange () {
     if(...) {
       this.transitionTo('someRoute', {id: 10});
     }
  },
  render () {
    <input ... onChange={this.handleChange} >
  }
});
```

However, I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.transitionTo is not a function
```

I can't find anything clear in the docs, and the example above is taken from [a random link I found while Googling](http://ricostacruz.com/cheatsheets/react-router.html). What am I missing/doing incorrect? I'm using `react-router v1.0.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of react router are you on?

Mixin's have more or less been abandoned by react. In react-router 1.0.0 ideally the way you would accomplish a redirect is by using `history.pushState`.

The rackt team has also just recently released an rc version for 2.0.0. Looks like you'll now need to manually include the history in your router instance - but it's not too different. [Check out the upgrade guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.0.0.md#no-default-history)

Comment: As stated in the question, I'm on `v1.0.3` which is currently still the default on npm via `npm install --save react-router`.

Comment: Didn't see that last paragraph.

Looks like that random link is referring to pre 1.0.0 version of react router. In your node routes, the Router now passes down the history object which is available in your router components via `this.props.history`. That object has the `pushState`.

the router 1.0.0 is pretty different than pre-1.0.0 so hopefully the links you've found aren't referencing the old stuff!

Comment: Also - If you're looking to call `history` from a non-route component, you will need to pass the history object into the component.

Comment: Oh, is that my issue? The component I'm navigating out of is a child of a route component, but it is not a route component itself. Does it matter what type of history I'm using? I'm using hashHistory right now since I don't want to deal with setting up the server to handle browserHistory.

Comment: Can I just pass it as a prop? Would you mind updating your answer with a more complete example based on my last comment? Thanks!

Comment: I got it worked out based on your advise to use `history.pushState` and looking at the right version of the docs! https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/advanced/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md :D